# How can I prevent rowsInserted signal from QFileSystemModel in special cases?

Tags: c++, qt, qfilesystemmodel, qmodelindex

i am programming a file explorer and I am using a QFileSysteModel as the base.
I noticed that the methods `QFileSystemModel::index()` and `QFileSystemModel::fetchMore` causing the model to emit the signal `rowsInserted`.

I have connected the `rowsInserted` signal to a slot which sends data about new inserted rows. The problem is that the rows which comes from `QFileSystemModel::index()` and `QFileSystemModel::fetchMore` are not really new, but added to the model by the QFileSystemModel itself, which causes trouble in my program.

I tried so set flags before using `QFileSystemModel::index()` and `QFileSystemModel::fetchMore` but it was not reliable especially with the `QFileSystemModel::fetchMore`.

Like:

```
m_blockRowInsert = true; // <-- blocks rowInserted for m_fileSysModel->index
auto index = m_fileSysModel->index(pathNew); // calls immediately rowsInserted
if(index.isValid())
{
    if(m_fileSysModel->canFetchMore(index))
    {
         m_blockRowInsert = true;// <-- does not work reliable because rowsInserted can be called more than once by fetchmore
         m_fileSysModel->fetchMore(index); // <-- calls rowsInserted after completing the function
    }
}
```

I tried to reset the flag like this:

```
void onRowsInserted(const QModelIndex &parent, int first, int last)
{
    if(m_blockRowInsert)
    {
        m_blockRowInsert = false;
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a little bit bewildered with your situation, can you just block signals before ```m_fileSysModel->fetchMore(index)```

Comment: It would be the same like setting up a flag, because i needed a defined location to unblock. I tried to block signals before, but i did not work since QFileSystemModel works in a different thread. I made it work with connecting a slot to the directoryLoaded signal, where I reset my flag.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [blockSignals](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#blockSignals) function. In that way, you block signals before `fetchMore` and enable signals after that.

```
...
if(m_fileSysModel->canFetchMore(index))
{
     this->blockSignals(true);
     m_fileSysModel->fetchMore(index);
     this->blockSignals(false);
}
...
```

I assumed that `this` is sender of `rowInserted` signals.